# Parse XML data in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing, sql-server-2012

I have a table tblUserData in SQL Server Database which has two columns:

```
tblUSerData(ID BIGINT, UserData XML)
```

The XML structure would be like:

```
<user>
   <name>
      Akshay
   </name>
   <age>
      23
   </age>
</user>
```

I want to write a stored procedure such that would read the table and return records of users who are more than 20 years old.
I am confused how to parse the table for data in **efficient** manner.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query could be written using the [exist() Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx)

```
select ID
from tblUserData
where UserData.exist('/user[age > 20]') = 1
```

From SQL Server 2012 SP1 you can use [Selective XML Indexes (SXI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj670108.aspx) and the index that supports the query above would look like this.

```
create selective xml index sxi_UserData on tblUserData(UserData)
for (
    u = '/user' as xquery 'node()' singleton,
    a = '/user/age' as xquery 'xs:double' singleton
    )
```

To use Selective XML Indexes you have to enabled it using [sp_db_selective_xml_index (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj670102.aspx)

For more information you can have a look at a number of blog posts by [Bob Beauchemin](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/getting-started-with-selective-xml-indexes-in-sql-server/).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that each row in tblUserData will only contain one user node, and one age node in that user you can use:

```
WHERE   UserData.value('user[1]/age[1]', 'int') > 20
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e54d4/1)**

Answer (score 0):

So I have created the table tblUserData and then I have written the query that will extract the Users whose age is more than 20

I have used the provided xml structure

```
<user>
  <name>
    Akshay
 </name>
 <age>
    23
 </age>
</user>
```

create table tblUserData (
ID BIGINT,

UserData xml
)

```
insert into tblUserData values (1, '<user>   <name>      Akshay   </name>   <age>         23   </age> </user>')

insert into tblUserData values (2, '<user>   <name>      Tom   </name>   <age>      26   </age> </user>')
```

Following is the query that will extract the users having age more than 20

```
 select node.value('name[1]', 'varchar(255)') as userName, node.value('age[1]','int')      as    age
 from dbo.tblUserData tblu
 CROSS APPLY UserData.nodes('/user') nodes(node)

 where node.value('age[1]', 'int') > 20
```